# How can i Re-Spawn a car if it rotates up to (180 degrees or more)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a car game. If i take a turn my car flips to (90 or 180 Degrees) and cannot flip again.

This is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _carPrefab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCarRoutine());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    // Sapwn the car if it rotate more than or = 180
    // creat a coroutine of type IEnumerator -- Yield event 
    // while loop 
    if (_carPrefab.transfor.rotate <= 180)
    {
        IEnumerator SpawnCarRoutine()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Vector3 posToSpawn = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                Instantiate(_carPrefab, posToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CarTemplate;

    private GameObject carInstance;

    void Start()
    {
        CreateNewCar();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var rotationVector = carInstance.transform.rotation * Vector3.up;

        if (rotationVector.y < 0)
        {
            Destroy(carInstance);
            CreateNewCar();
        }
    }

    void CreateNewCar()
    {
        carInstance = Instantiate(CarTemplate);
        carInstance.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

To make a new car, it instantiates a copy and then sets it as active (the template is inactive).

To check if it's upside down. It takes the rotation of the car and then multiplies it by a vector pointing up. You can imagine it as a line pointing upwards from the roof of the car.

If this line is pointing down, the car will be upside down. So it check if the Y value of the line is less than 0, then makes a new car if it is.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (_carPrefab.transfor.rotate <= 180)
> {
>     IEnumerator SpawnCarRoutine()
>     {
>         while (true)
>         {
> ...
> }
> ```

This is nonsense. It's worth getting to grips with how functions work in C# or you will keep running into problems trying to write things like this.

You want to check if the car is pointing upside down. You can do this with comparing the angle between the car's local *up* direction vector, to the world's *down* direction vector.

Like this

```
var angle = Vector3.Angle(_carPrefab.transform.up, Vector3.down);
```

Then if this angle is less than some threshold, say within 30 degrees, you can call your respawn script.

```
void Update()
{
    if(CarIsUpsideDown())
        Respawn();
}

bool CarIsUpsideDown()
{
    return Vector3.Angle(_carPrefab.transform.up, Vector3.down) < 30;
}
```

However, this will trigger if the car is upside down for even one frame, which you might not want. You could instead say if the car is upside down for a number of frames, or take a rolling average.

Something like

```
void Start()
{ 
    StartCoroutine(CarUpsideDownTest());
}

IEnumerator CarUpsideDownTest()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(!CarIsUpsideDown()
        {
            count = 0;
            continue;
        }
        
        count ++;
        
        if(count > 10)
            RespawnCar();

        yeild return null; // wait for next frame
    }
}
```